# How to alarm on Kubernetes prometheus pod throwing particular error messages in its logs

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I have a K8s pod that is up and running. However, it is throwing errors in logs saying it has reached limits on number of time series that can be supported.

Question -- How do I setup alerting/monitoring of this error so that I be notified as soon as this happens.

Are there some system level metrics that we can tap into? Or are there some alarms I can add based on log error messages?

Comment: Can you add relevant log lines to the question? AFAIK, the number of time series is not limited directly. It can be limited indirectly by heap size, retention size, etc.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor? Could you provide logs as @anemyte mentioned?